# Youtube get user uploads in php

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to get the full list of videos uploaded by a user.

I am using the following url:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/uploads?v2&alt=json

And using curl in php to get the contents.

But I am getting only 25 results. If I use the max-results, the max is 50.

What should I use in order to get the whole list?

Answer (score 1):

After replacing 'username' with a valid name the response shows a url link for the next request in the response you get. Look for: {"rel":"next","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/uploads?alt=json&start-index=26&max-results=25"}
As you can see another parameter is added: 'start-index'. Which you also can add yourself

BTW. I assume you know there is a typing error in your example. You set the version parameter by using 'v=2' instead of 'v2'.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) for this purpose.
You can get to use [PHP examples](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/#git/samples/php) in [YouTube API Samples](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/) project.